# How to make applescript hold a key for 2 seconds

Tags: keyboard, applescript, games

So I am trying to make a script that moves me forward and backward to prevent afk in a game but the game is not registering the key as it is too short here is what I have so far.

```
repeat 100 times
        tell application "System Events" to keystroke "w" using command down
    delay (random number from 0.5 to 3)
        tell application "System Events" to keystroke "s" using command down
    delay (random number from 3 to 4)
end repeat
```

Answer (score 6):

You probably want key down & up as separate events...

```
repeat 100 times
    tell application "System Events"
        key down {command}
        key down "w"
        delay (random number from 0.5 to 3)
        key up "w"

        key down "s"
        delay (random number from 3 to 4)
        key up "s"
        key up {command}
    end tell
end repeat
```

<s>[untested as I've nothing to really test it on]</s>
Now tested as working on a similar game structure.

Comment: @klanomath - tweaked so it at least compiles, but I still have nothing I can really test it on

Comment: EventViewer is an app to test the keyboard mapping mods made with Karabiner - it's ideal to test keyboard/mouse events.

Comment: Thanks - Not something I'd ever seen, had Karabiner briefly, but really only for testing things in Ask Different. Will re-investigate.

Comment: Hmm now it "compiles" properly but using 1 instead of 100 and `option` instead of `command` it writes only two **å**s in a word document (prepending `activate application "Microsoft Word"`.

Comment: mhm, but it's to generate movement in a game of some sort, so the length of press will be registered as activity/walking etc in the game. I've now tested it in another game & it does provide avatar movement, sufficient to prevent it from going idle. I agree in a text scenario it just generates single unicode letters.

Comment: Now we have to know what kind of moves cmd-s/w initiate. There is probably a difference between key-down-cmd, key-down-w, delay, key-up-w **and** key-down-cmd, key-down-w, key-up-w, delay.