# Making an AppleScript that holds down a key

Tags: keyboard, applescript

So I'm trying to make a script that holds down a key like Left option. But I don't want to use something like

```
tell application "x"
    keystroke *keycode*
end tell
```

I tried doing that, but the app I'm trying to make it work for won't accept it. 
So I thought of trying to make a script that just holds down a key (specifically a modifier key) for an indefinite time.

Is there any solution?

Comment: Do you need [longer than 2 seconds](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/248861/how-to-make-applescript-hold-a-key-for-2-seconds)?

Answer (score 1):

Try running your code using the `key down` & `key up` features of AppleScript.

## code:

```
tell application "System Events"
    key down option
    delay 5
    key up option
end tell
```

Answer (score -2):

`keystroke` is actually part of the application "System Events, so try something like this:

```
tell application "x" to activate
delay 1
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "x"
        repeat n times
            keystroke "keycode"
        end repeat
    end tell
end tell
```

Where x is the application/process and n is a number.

Comment: Please, don't guess! Your script simply repeats keycode n times, but doesn't hold down a key!