# Hold keyboard key and hold mouse button with AppleScript

Tags: applescript

I was looking to make a script where I simply hold a and hold leftclick. I got to here but I'm not sure if I did it right.

```
tell application "System Events"    
    repeat 5 times
        key down "s"
        click
    end repeat
end tell
```

Comment: Have a look at the _third-party command line utility_ [**cliclick**](https://github.com/BlueM/cliclick) that can be run in **Terminal** by itself, or a _shell script_, of from **AppleScript** using the `do shell script` _command_.

Comment: Repeat of [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/263989/making-an-applescript-that-holds-down-a-key)

Answer (score 1):

You may find it easier to use a Macro App to do your work.
The application Repeater from the App Store
https://apps.apple.com/us/app/repeater/id443370764?mt=12
allows you to record mouse and keyboard clicks.
Record your "a" press and your "mouse click/hold" and then set the Repeater app to repeat the action.
It will continue to run until you press a key or move the mouse manually.

Answer (score 0):

### Keyboard

You can hold a key down using ‘key down’ then ‘sleep n’ for some duration before ‘key up’ to release the key.

[How to make applescript hold a key for 2 seconds](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/248861/37797)

### Mouse

> There is no AppleScript feature, or one in Script Editor that allows you to hold down a click for any designated length of time. A click is a discrete event, and then AppleScript goes on to the next activity.

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/251556616?answerId=253006483022#253006483022